# Need help in re-order / sort Bars in Bar Chart in Qliksense

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to reorder the Bars in bar chart in qliksense. Below is the order which I have to sort the bars.

```
NEW
IN_PROGRESS_PL
ASSIGNED
IN_PROGRESS_SPOC
RESOLVED/CLOSED
FBS E2S BACKLOG
CANCELLED
DUPLICATE
```

But by default the bars are ordered in alphabetical order or by the numbers, I have tried the below solution, but it still didn't rearranged the bars.

Default order :

[image]

```
Match('NEW','IN_PROGRESS_PL','ASSIGNED','IN_PROGRESS_SPOC','RESOLVED/CLOSED','FBS E2S BACKLOG' , 'CANCELLED','DUPLICATE' )
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in [Match](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/match.htm) is the targeted field.

If we have data like:

```
RawData:
Load * inline [
Stage       , IdeasCount
ASSIGNED    , 63
CANCELLED   , 11
INTERNAL_123, 2
IN_PROGRESS1, 20
IN_PROGRESS2, 47
];
```

Then the sorting expression will be:

```
=match(Stage, 'IN_PROGRESS1', 'ASSIGNED', 'IN_PROGRESS2', 'INTERNAL_123', 'CANCELLED')
```

The sorting properties:

[image: chart properties]

And the result chart will have the correct sorting:
[image: result]

### P.S. (1)

Have to mention that if the value is not found in the `Match` function then the function will return `null` and thus the corresponding bar will be pushed in the front. In this case you can wrap the match in `if` statement and if no matching value is found then assign some large number:

```
= if( match(Field, 'value1', 'value2' ...) > 0,
      match(Field, 'value1', 'value2' ...),
      1000
  )
```

### P.S. (2)

In your case you can also use [Dual](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Dual.htm) function to create "default" sort order for a specific field.

If we change the script to:

```
RawData:
Load 
  Dual(Stage, OrderId) as Stage,
  IdeasCount
;
Load * inline [
Stage       , IdeasCount, OrderId
ASSIGNED    , 63        , 2
CANCELLED   , 11        , 5
INTERNAL_123, 2         , 4
IN_PROGRESS1, 20        , 1
IN_PROGRESS2, 47        , 3
]
;
```

The result table will look the same - with two fields only `Stage` and `IdeasCount`. But in the background each value of `Stage` field will have and number representation (based on the initial `OrderId` field). And as a side effect of that the `auto` sorting option will sort the field data by its internal number representation and the chart will "sort itself" correctly

[image: default sorting]